# Parameter sets - ensure parameters exist

Tags: powershell, parameter-sets

I'm trying to use Parameter Sets to replicate this functionality:

```
if (($hostName) -or ($databaseName) -and (!$databasePassword)) {
    throw "If hostName or databaseName specified, you must use databasePassword parameter."
}
```

Simple example of what I have so far:

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName="Test")]
[string]$hostName,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName="Test")]
[string]$databaseName,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName="Test")]
[string]$databasePassword
```

This is not working. I can supply `$hostName` without `$databasePassword` for example, or `$dataBasename` without `$databasePassword` and the function runs.

What am I missing?

Comment: _`Mandatory=$false`_ - Think about it for two seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make two parameter sets, make `$Hostname` mandatory in the first, make `$DatabaseName` optional in the first and mandatory in the other, make `$DatabasePassword` mandatory in both.

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='host')]
Param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='host', Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$Hostname,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='host', Mandatory=$false)]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='dbname', Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$DatabaseName,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='host', Mandatory=$true)]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='dbname', Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$DatabasePassword
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `databasePassword` to be mandatory?

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName="Test")]
[string]$databasePassword
```